# Pass multiple parameters to scons builder command

Tags: python, scons

I'd like to run a command that combines multiple files into one. So if I create two files:

```
echo 1 > a.txt
echo 2 > b.txt
```

And then I create the following scons file:

```
import os
import os.path as op

env = Environment()
b = Builder(action="cat $SOURCE")

builders = {"b":b}
env.Append(BUILDERS=builders)

env.b("x.txt", ["a.txt", "b.txt"])
```

It only calls `cat` with the argument `a.txt`:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cat a.txt
1
scons: done building targets.
```

Can I make it call `cat` with both arguments at the same time?

```
cat a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: just do `cat a.txt b.txt > c.txt`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just have to define your Action as "cat $SOURCES" then (note the added "S" at the end).

Comment: I wish things were always so simple :)

Comment: With SCons they are...most of the time. ;)